# Jquery for checkbox is hitting debugger more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox

I am working on Mvc.Grid and facing a problem with onclick of a checkbox. There are list of Profiles in the grid and there is a checkbox in each row for each profile. I need to get the list of Id's that are checked. So my jquery code is

```
    $('.checkboxClick').click(function () {
        debugger;
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        CheckPaymentSelected(id);
    });

    function CheckPaymentSelected(id) {
        debugger;
        if ($("#" + id).is(':checked'))
        {
            debugger;
            selectedProfilesID.push(id);

        }
        else {
            var removeItem = id;
            selectedProfilesID = jQuery.grep(selectedProfilesID, function (value) {
                return value != removeItem;
            });
        }

    }
```

So OnClick of one checkbox the debugger should hit only once. But instead the debugger is hitting 10 times. My grid length is also 10. Can anybody help me out with this. Instead of click function I have also tried OnChange function but all in vain. My checkbox looks like this:

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after giving deep thought as to what could be the solution, I tried doing this and surprisingly and luckily it worked for me:

```
$("input#@item.imdcode").click(function() {
        debugger;
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        CheckPaymentSelected(id);
    });

    function CheckPaymentSelected(id) {
        debugger;
        if ($("#" + id).is(':checked')) {
            debugger;
            selectedProfilesID.push(id);

        }
        else {
            var removeItem = id;
            selectedProfilesID = jQuery.grep(selectedProfilesID, function (value) {
                return value != removeItem;
            });
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.checkboxClick').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        if($(this).is(':checked')
        {
         debugger;
         selectedProfilesID.push(id);
        }
        else{
           var removeItem = id;
           selectedProfilesID = jQuery.grep(selectedProfilesID, function (value) {
           return value != removeItem;
        });
        }
    });
```

Try this. I think this will resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks Deepak for your reply. But your code also dint work for me. I dont understand what the problem is. The same code that I posted is working in my other pages but not for this page.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('.checkboxClick').click(function () {
       if(this.checked) {
        debugger;
        var id = this.id;
        CheckPaymentSelected(id);
        }
    });
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/A3xfD/)**

Comment: Thanks for replying so soon. I saw your demo. Understood what you tried to do and convey me. But sadly it dint work in my project. The debugger is still hitting 10 times.